# Usa-se mais "pleno" ou "sênior" quando se trata de um título profissional?

Tags: vocabulário

Ao procurar em vários sites de empregos, tenho visto duas "versões" que indicam a experiência de um certo cargo ou responsabilidade.

Por exemplo:

> Desenvolvedor .NET Sênior
>
> Desenvolvedor Pleno de Java
>
> Gerente de Projetos Sênior

É possível que também haja algo parecido com a palavra *Júnior*.

As minhas dúvidas são:

- Qual dessas palavras é *mais correta*, gramaticalmente? (sendo que é possível que ambas sejam exatamente iguais)
- Qual dessas palavras é *mais usada*, ou seja, utilizada por mais empresas/companhias quando estão à busca de talento?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Os termos *Pleno* e *Sênior* (bem como o *Júnior* que mencionaste) são usados para definir o conhecimento e experiência de candidatos a uma vaga de emprego na área de TI. Já vi definições que levam em conta o tempo de experiência profissional, bem como o domínio da linguagem de programação pretendida.

As definições que vi consideram:

- Junior: até 2 anos de experiência profissional, ou domínio de 80% da linguagem de programação, isto é, o profissional não conhece todos mecanismos da linguagem.
- Pleno: de 2 a 5 anos anos de experiência profissional, ou domínio de 100% da linguagem, isto é, domina a linguagem.
- Sênior: mais de 5 anos de experiência profissional, ou *domínio de 120%* da linguagem, isto é, não é limitado pela linguagem, inclusive já tendo criado mecanismos que nela não existiam anteriormente.

Comment: Ahh, então não são sinónimos como pensara - são níveis diferentes!

Comment: @brazilianldsjaguar Exato! As definiõçes exatas são um tanto quanto elásticas e podem variar até mesmo de empresa para empresa, mas de maneira geral pode se dizer que júnior < pleno < sênior.

Comment: O tempo das definições não possuem regra absolutamente alguma. Eu mesmo por exemplo, fiquei em uma empresa 4 anos como Jr, depois eu mudei para outra empresa e fui direto para Sênior (mas com um aumento mínimo no salário). Se eu não tivesse mudado de empresa eu teria continuado como Jr por pelo menos uns 10 anos. Ou seja, esses tempos são ilusórios e só servem para mostrar qual é a ideia por detrás desses termos.

Comment: Não se pode dominar mais do que o total (100%) de algo... é como comer 120% do total, não dá - implica que o total é só parcial. Da mesma forma que não se pode dominar menos de 0% da linguagem. (Exceto metaforicamente.)

Comment: @ANeves Estava falando metaforicamente, por isso que indiquei usando itálico. A idéia dos 120% é que o profissional não é limitado pela linguagem. Se for preciso algo que a linguagem não oferece, ele é capaz de criar usando-a, efetivamente aumentando a linguagem.

Comment: 120% não existe.

Comment: @JorgeB. pode parecer estranho, mas no contexto de retorno de investimento (entre outros), é comum usarem-se percentagens acima de 100%. Pode ler a subsecção [Moving beyond ROI](http://www.investopedia.com/articles/basics/10/guide-to-calculating-roi.asp).

Comment: Ser comum não quer dizer que seja correto @Armfoot .

Comment: @JorgeB. Certo, porém _correto_ ou _errado_ depende do contexto. Citando o Dr. Math: [«there is such a thing as a percentage larger than 
100%, but not everything can have a percentage larger than 100%»](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/58166.html)